# Numerical Methods for finding the Roots of $f(x)=\sin^2(\frac{33}{x}\pi)+\sin^2(x \pi)$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, numerical-methods, roots

This question is a continuation of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297924/numerical-methods-for-finding-the-roots-of-fx-left-cos-frac33x-pi-rig) one; but this time $$f(x)=\sin^2(\frac{33}{x}\pi)+\sin^2(x \pi)$$ Everything about that question holds for this one: I'm looking for numerical root-finding algorithms for this function that approximate the roots fairly accurately. I found that a lot of popular iterative algorithms like Newton's won't work for this function (at least not in this form) as the roots are also minima. And, just like last time, assume I have an interval where only one root must lie in. I am focused on roots $>1$ and $<33$. I picked this equations because the roots can be easily found: $1,3,11,33$. I want to be able to compare the algorithm's accuracy.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96623/discussion-on-question-by-quote-dave-numerical-methods-for-finding-the-roots-of).